# Python: Trying to create the equivalent of and(or(value,value,value))

Tags: python, boolean-logic

Okay so here's my dilemma:

I'm working on a FAQ bot for a subreddit. I'm having trouble with boolean logic and could use a pair of more experienced eyes (this is my first adventure in Python). Right now the bot is basically spamming the test subreddit I created. Rather than share that specific information, here's an example that is showing the exact problem I'm running into:

```
#Define Key Words
##################################
#System Requirements Definitions
sysReq1 = ('system requirements' and '?')
sysReq2 = ('can' and ('handle' or 'play' or 'run') and ('netbook' or 'notebook' or 'pc' or 'mac' or 'macbook' or 'laptop' or 'comp' or 'computer') and '?')
#System Requirements Response
sysReqResponse = 'PROGRESS'
##################################
testString1 = "i hate this"
#intended result for 1: nothing
testString2 = "is that real?"
#intended result for 2: nothing
testString3 = "What are the system requirements?"
#intended result for 3: 'PROGRESS'
print testString1
if (sysReq1 or sysReq2) in testString1.lower():
    print sysReqResponse
print testString2
if (sysReq1 or sysReq2) in testString2.lower():
    print sysReqResponse
print testString3
if (sysReq1 or sysReq2) in testString2.lower():
print sysReqResponse
```

When you run it, it displays:

```
i hate this
is that real?
PROGRESS
What are the system requirements?
PROGRESS
```

it keeps returning a value for testString2. I think it has something to do with '?' but really have no clue how or why or what to do about it. Help!

EDIT: Here's what I want it to display:

When you run it, it displays:

```
i hate this
is that real?
What are the system requirements?
PROGRESS
```

So far, I found that if I change my `sysReq1 = ('system requirements' and '?')` to `sysReq1 = 'system requirements' '?'` and only check the `if` for `sysReq1`, it returns the fight values. Problem is I really need those `or` statements to reduce clutter/redundancy.

The reason sysReq2 is there is because some people ask a different question for the same answer :

- Can it run on my netbook?
- Can my PC handle it?
- Can I play it on my mac?

and this is excluding the variations of 'Will I be able to', but you get the idea. All of these should return the same value (in this case, "PROGRESS")

Comment: What do you expect `('system requirements' and '?')` to do?

Comment: I expect it to be stored as the value 'sysReq1'

Comment: I'm not talking about the variable assignment. I'm talking about the logical operators.

Comment: Oh - To make sure that both are present when checked against the criteria.

Comment: Logical operators don't really work like that.

Comment: Well... How can I check for the words "system requirements" and "?" in the phrase "What are the system requirements" in a way that would also check for it in "Have the system requirements been released yet?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any), [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all), and [generators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) can help you out here.

### The code

```
#Define Key Words
##################################
#System Requirements Definitions
sysReq1 = ['system requirements', '?']
sysReq2 = [['can']
          ,['handle', 'play', 'run']
          ,['netbook', 'notebook', 'pc', 'mac', 'macbook', 'laptop', 'comp', 'computer']
          ,['?']
          ]
def test(testString):
    lowerTestString = testString.lower()
    return all(i in lowerTestString for i in sysReq1) or all(any(j in lowerTestString for j in i) for i in sysReq2)
#System Requirements Response
sysReqResponse = 'PROGRESS'
##################################
testString1 = "i hate this"
#intended result for 1: nothing
testString2 = "is that real?"
#intended result for 2: nothing
testString3 = "What are the system requirements?"
#intended result for 3: 'PROGRESS'
print testString1
if test(testString1):
    print sysReqResponse
print testString2
if test(testString2):
    print sysReqResponse
print testString3
if test(testString3):
    print sysReqResponse
```

The function isn't strictly necessary, but it does make the code more maintainable. If you need to change the check, it only changes in one place.

### What's going on here?

First, we converted the two sets of strings into a list and a list of lists. The requirement then becomes, "The string must contain all elements of `sysReq1` or at least one element from every sublist of `sysReq2`."

We accomplish checking this condition by combining generators with the `any` and `all` functions. After storing the `lower` to avoid calling this repeatedly, we create a generator (which amounts to an iterator) of booleans. Each boolean tells us whether a single element of `sysReq1` is contained in the lowered. Then we pass this iterator to the first `all`, which checks if the list contains all `True`s. If so, the `all` function returns `True` and the second check is short circuited. Otherwise, it returns `False` and Python moves on past the `or.`

The check for `sysReq2` is more complicated. First, we create a generator of booleans for each sublist; this is inside the `any` call. This list contains a set of booleans as to whether each element of the sublist is in the lowered string. The `any` call returns `True` if any element in this list of booleans (based on the sublist) is `True`. (It short circuits, by the way, and since we're using a generator, the checks following a `True` aren't even run, unlike if we had used a list.) Then we create another generator; this one contains the results of each sublist test (all the `any` calls). Then `all` is called on this generator, which checks if the question contained an element from all sublists.

I would note that users can enter nonsense questions if they're typing them in directly. For example, `'Play can netbook kuguekf ugifugfj ugufsgjf nugjfgjfgj?'` would pass this check.

### Summary

Use generators to run your tests that return boolean values. Use `any` and `all` to combine iterables of boolean values.

### Edit

Based on comments, here's an alternate solution that [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)s the input string by white space and uses [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)s instead of `list`s. I also added a test case from the sample questions you listed to ensure that the second part of the `or` is being hit.

```
#Define Key Words
##################################
#System Requirements Definitions
sysReq1 = set(['system', 'requirements'])
sysReq2 = [set(['can'])
          ,set(['handle', 'play', 'run'])
          ,set(['netbook', 'notebook', 'pc', 'mac', 'macbook', 'laptop', 'comp', 'computer'])
          ]
def test(testString):
    if not testString.endswith('?'):
        return False

    lowerTestString = set(testString.rstrip('?').lower().split())
    return  lowerTestString.issuperset(sysReq1) or all(not lowerTestString.isdisjoint(i) for i in sysReq2)
#System Requirements Response
sysReqResponse = 'PROGRESS'
##################################
testString1 = "i hate this"
#intended result for 1: nothing
testString2 = "is that real?"
#intended result for 2: nothing
testString3 = "What are the system requirements?"
#intended result for 3: 'PROGRESS'
testString4 = "Can my PC handle it?"
#intended result for 4: 'PROGRESS'
print testString1
if test(testString1):
    print sysReqResponse
print testString2
if test(testString2):
    print sysReqResponse
print testString3
if test(testString3):
    print sysReqResponse
print testString4
if test(testString4):
    print sysReqResponse
```

I think this is fairly straightforward. Note that the `set` constructor takes an iterable, so I'm passing lists in just for that. The "not disjoint" part might be a bit confusing; it's just making sure the intersection isn't empty. I used that in hopes that the function is implemented so that it doesn't compute the entire intersection. The question mark was problematic since it wasn't separated by a space, so I just made sure the string ended in a question mark and [`rstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)ed it off.

Actually, this implementation might be cleaner and more maintainable than the one with lots of generators.

Comment: Oh my sweet dear baby jesus this is amazing. Testing it out on the example and then testing it out with the PRAW!

Comment: @user2526254 Welcome to Python. =)

Comment: You can do this, but without further specification of the query structure it doesn't save you much.  This still hardcodes exactly two queries, and hardcodes that each is an AND of sublists which are ORs, and hardcodes that these two queries should be OR-ed together.  If you're going to hardcode all of that, I'd just as soon hardcode the original two queries, because it's more explicit.  If the queries have a specified, known structure (like and of ors), then you can write a system to handle them, but the question doesn't say that, so this solution could break on a slightly different query.

Comment: The end-game plan for the bot is to have multiple sections. i.e. #System Requirements is one section, another would be #Save Files, #Release Date... and more. My question is: would the `def test(teststring):` be usable in those sections or would I have to define a new function for each section? If I'm not making sense I can link a pastebin with what I'm thinking.

Comment: @BrenBarn Yeah, the logic is hard coded in the code. I don't think you can do anything about that besides create a natural language parser or make the users specify the logic themselves, neither of which is very practical. I suppose you could restrict the users to a specific syntax and avoid checking questions altogether. If you'd really prefer to write out a string of `and`s and `or`s, your choice. I think that's harder to write and maintain, personally; you'll definitely have to do some good formatting to make it readable.

Comment: @user2526254 If they have different outputs, you'll need separate checks. In that case, I would probably just have a function that returns the output based on a [`if`/`elif`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm) statement. If you're just using the same output for all of them, you could probably wrap everything inside another `any`/generator.

Comment: Doing some experimentation with this and noticed something. You mentioned that users could enter nonsense questions... but it also responds to anything that has part of the key word in it. ie it will respond to `Playasdocandsadaionetbook?` (Play, Can, Netbook, ?). How can I fix this so that it only responds to a FULL word?

Comment: The workaround I came up with is to add a space before and after each word and doubling the size of each list ie `' netbook', 'netbook '` but it's not exactly an ideal solution

Comment: Oh god I just realized that that won't work... At least not with `all(i in lowerTestString for i in list#)`. The ones that worked in that one will work in `all(any(j in lowerTestString for j in i) for i in list1)` but then I have to figure out how to change those ones >.>

Comment: Hm. You could try splitting the string by white space. You'll have to have more nested generators to loop over the list of words, though. (Note that using straight `and`s and `or`s will have these same problems; I'm inclined to think it would be even more cumbersome to deal with using those.) At that point, it might be worthwhile to switch to sets instead of lists and do intersection to keep the code simpler. Natural language interpretation is a very, very difficult problem.

Comment: You lost me halfway through that :V I came up with a pseudo-solution, but every once in a while it still flags on some things that it shouldnt. No idea how sets/intersections work so I'll look into it

Comment: @user2526254 Added an implementation of what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems.  First, you can't use `and` and `or` to "store" some kind of comparison operator for use later.  When you write `and` and `or` the result is evaluated immediately.  The rules for that are described in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

Second, you can't use `and` and `or` with `in` that way.  `in` does not "distribute over" `and` and and `or`.  Writing `('A' and 'B') in x` doesn't mean "A in x and B in x".  It evaluates `('A' and 'B')` *first* (which in this case will give you `'B'`) and then checks whether that single result is in `x`.

You can't achieve what you want with simple operators.  There's no way to use just the `and` and `or` operators to store a complex query like that that you can apply later.  You're going to have to convert your criteria into functions and call them with the "test strings" as arguments:

```
def sysReq1(x):
    return 'system requirements' in x and '?' in x

>>> testString2 = "is that real?"
... testString3 = "What are the system requirements?"
... print testString2
... if sysReq1(testString2.lower()):
...     print "2 passed the test"
... print testString3
... if sysReq1(testString3.lower()):
...     print "3 passed the test"
is that real?
What are the system requirements?
3 passed the test
```

I'd suggest you work through [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to get a handle on the basics of Python.

Comment: I understand what you mean here, but the point is that I'm trying to condense things down. The purpose of this bot is to look for questions that require the same answer, but are asked differently. So rather than create 24 different queries, I want to condense all those variations into sysReq2.

Comment: @user2526254: You can.  You just need to make `sysReq2` a function that calls `in` on each piece and `and`/`or`s those together.  You can't condense it down to just `and`s and `or`s, because it won't work.

Comment: There's no way to automatically create a variation on a list? i.e. def sysReq2(x) return 'can' in x and '(Handle/Play/Run)' in x and '(Type)' in x and '?' in x vs having to type it out for all 24 variations (edit oh god comments can't be formatted)

Comment: @user2526254: Not directly, no.  You could of course write a function that constructs such a thing, but if you are a beginner with Python that's probably more work.  Python isn't a query language and isn't really aimed at constructing complex and/or queries from literal strings.

Comment: So, basically, a lot more effort than making 24 variations. Crap. Well, thanks for helping. Changing to functions really helps out. I'd upvote your response if I could but it apparently doesn't let new accounts do so.

Comment: @user2526254: You should still be able to accept it as the answer (click the check mark) if it answers your questions.  Writing a thing to help you make queries instead of doing them manually may be worth doing, but what I mean is that if you are new enough to Python that you don't know what `'A' and 'B'` does, you should back up and work through the tutorial before attempting to write something like that.

Comment: I'm just using the knowledge I have from excel and doing trial and error while seeking guidance when I get stuck in a few places. I know that the tutorial is the recommended way to learn, but since this is more of a hobby, I'm going at it the way I feel is more enjoyable. All that being said, I checked your response and will work toward what I wanted because 24 variations isn't bad but if I want to add another element it jumps higher and higher.

Comment: @BrenBarn "Python isn't a query language and isn't really aimed at constructing complex and/or queries from literal strings." I think that's an overly broad statement. A number of Python constructs **are** geared toward making your code more declarative, especially when it comes to lists and operations or aggregates over them. This is a good thing since it makes code easier to understand, read, and write. "You can't achieve what you want with simple operators." Depends on your definition of simple, as you can see in my answer. You can avoid manually and/oring all those together.

Answer (score 0):

In python, the output of an expression containing BOOLEAN OPERATORS need not be a BOOLEAN (http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) 
e.g., `sysReq1 = ('system requirements' and '?')` will make `sysReq1='?'` and note here that `sysReq1` is not a boolean value but a string equalling to QUESTION MARK. Similarly, `sysReq2` will also be equal to `?` . And also, look for TRUTH VALUE TESTING in the above link as that will explain what values will be considered as FALSE expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the information. How would you achieve the results I'm looking for then? Is there an alternative to boolean operators? An example would be helpful because this is pretty much all greek to me.

Comment: Can you tell us the expected output you want the code to print ?

Comment: I'll update the original post, but only 'testString3' should return 'PROGRESS'